# What are the conditions for the solution set of $f(x,y,z) = 0$, $g(x,y,z) = 0$ to be a 1-manifold without boundary?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 209 question 3, it is asked that

[image]

and I have given the following (**partial**) answer to it:

### Solution:

Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ denote the set of solutions that that system of equations satisfies the given condition. Then

if $$det ( \frac{\partial (f,g)}{\partial (y,z)} ) \not = 0 \quad \forall x \in M,$$
by the implicit function theorem, there exists $a_y, a_z, b_y, b_z: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^r$   s.t

$$f(x, a_y(x), a_z (x)) = 0 \quad and \quad g(x, b_y (x), b_z (x)) = \quad \forall x \in N,$$
where $N = \{ \pi_1 (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R} | (x,y,z) \in M\}.$

Now define $\alpha : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by

$$ \alpha (x) = (x, f(x, a_y(x), a_z (x)), g(x, b_y (x), b_z (x))) \quad \forall x \in N,$$

and observe that $D\alpha$ exists (because of our assumtion) and equal to

$$D \alpha = [1, Df, Dg]^T,$$
which is rank 1 for all $x \in N.$

Moreover, it is clear that $\alpha \in C^r$.

However, [as it is in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883301/for-the-coordinate-path-alpha-z-z-gz-how-to-show-that-alpha-1), I couldn't show the continuity of $\alpha^{-1}$.

Hence the question;

### Question:

How can we show the continuity of $\alpha^{-1}$, and is the rest of the answer (assuming we have answered the first part) is correct ?